# Error in spark scala ide while reading nested complete JSON file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a complex nested json data  file as below and I am trying to consume the data and convert it as

per the below class

```
case class DeviceData (id: Int, device: String)
```

where id = 0 and

```
device = "{""device_id"": 0, ""device_type"": ""sensor-ipad"",""battery"":[{""type"": ""electrical""} ,{""type"": ""solar""}], ""ip"": ""68.161.225.1"", ""cca3"": ""USA"", ""cn"": ""United States"", ""temp"": 25, ""signal"": 23, ""battery_level"": 8, ""c02_level"": 917, ""timestamp"" :1475600496 }"
```

But I am stuck at the first step itself while consuming the data and converting them to a simple data frame and getting _corrupt_record error. Please advise what mistake I have made. I am using Spark version 2.4.5

export1.json

```
0,"{""device_id"": 0, ""device_type"": ""sensor-ipad"",""battery"":[{""type"": ""electrical""} ,{""type"": ""solar""}], ""ip"": ""68.161.225.1"", ""cca3"": ""USA"", ""cn"": ""United States"", ""temp"": 25, ""signal"": 23, ""battery_level"": 8, ""c02_level"": 917, ""timestamp"" :1475600496 }"
1,"{""device_id"": 1, ""device_type"": ""sensor-igauge"",""battery"":[{""type"": ""electrical""} ,{""type"": ""solar""}], ""ip"": ""213.161.254.1"", ""cca3"": ""NOR"", ""cn"": ""Norway"", ""temp"": 30, ""signal"": 18, ""battery_level"": 6, ""c02_level"": 1413, ""timestamp"" :1475600498 }"
2,"{""device_id"": 2, ""device_type"": ""sensor-ipad"",""battery"":[{""type"": ""electrical""} ,{""type"": ""solar""}], ""ip"": ""88.36.5.1"", ""cca3"": ""ITA"", ""cn"": ""Italy"", ""temp"": 18, ""signal"": 25, ""battery_level"": 5, ""c02_level"": 1372, ""timestamp"" :1475600500 }"
```

and my spark code is as below

```scala
package sparkWCExample.spWCExample

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import java.util.Formatter.DateTime
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._  // include the Spark Types to define our schema
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ // include the Spark helper functions
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_timestamp

case class DeviceData (id: Int, device: String)

object DatasetExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Start now")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Scala WordCount Example").setMaster("local[1]")
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).appName("CsvExample").master("local").getOrCreate()
    val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext
    import spark.implicits._

val readJSONDF = spark.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles("C:\\Sankha\\Study\\data\\complex-nested-json\\export1.json").values).toDF()
  println(readJSONDF.show())
}
}
```

I am getting the exception

```
+--------------------+
|     _corrupt_record|
+--------------------+
|0,"{""device_id""...|
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sc.wholeTextFiles` creates a PairRDD with the key being the file name and the value the content of the whole file. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/vaquarkhan/vaquarkhan/wiki/sc.textFile-vs-sc.WholeTextFiles).

You might want to use [spark.read.text](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@text(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) and then split the lines afterwards:

```scala
val df = spark.read.text("export1.json")
  .map(row => {
    val s = row.getAs[String](0)
    val index = s.indexOf(',')
    DeviceData(s.substring(0, index).toInt, s.substring(index+1))
  })
df.show
```

prints

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|              device|
+---+--------------------+
|  0|"{""device_id"": ...|
|  1|"{""device_id"": ...|
|  2|"{""device_id"": ...|
+---+--------------------+
```